# How to keep round corners using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

From the following image [image: image with round corners], I want to hide the second button,

using `javascript`, and I need for the first button to have round corners.

After I hide the second button using javascript, the first button has a rectangular shape on the right side:

[image: image after display none]

If I delete the button node, bootstrap sets the rounded corners, but this is not useful.

This is what i need, by using javascript:

[image: this is what i need]

The standard `bootstrap` html button structure:

```
<div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-mini action_select customSelect" id="btn_bulk_action" data-toggle="button" disabled="disabled">Reply<span class="reply2"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-mini action_select" data-toggle="button" id="btn_bulk_action_archive" disabled="disabled" style="
    display: none;
">Archive<i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: do you need the archive button at all or are you just showing or hiding it depending on what's happening on your page? I imagine the right side of the reply button isn't rounded because it's in a group so if you don't need the archive button, get rid of the group, if you do need archive then you could maybe hide the group and show a reply button that isn't in a group or apply border radius to it via jquery/javascript when archive is hidden?

Comment: i need to show it or hide it depending on whats happening on the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your buttons are in a button group, and by default bootstrap expects more than one button.

You should either remove the button group or modify the css to round the button if there is only one.

Anyway to answer your question, the simplest way via jquery:

```
$('.btn-group').removeClass('btn-group');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uVffe/

Although you might want to add the class back in again so I would:

```
$('.btn-group').addClass('btn-group-single');
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group-single > .btn:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

Then you can remove it in the future:

```
$('.btn-group').removeClass('btn-group-single');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uVffe/1/

A toggle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uVffe/3/